# Determine the distance between 2 lines with variable parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

Can you explain or give me an example of how to proceed in this case: I have two $r$ and $s$ lines and I have two variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I have to determine the distance between $r$ and $s$ so that it is equal to $\sqrt{10}$ how can I do it?
$$r\equiv \begin{cases} x=3z-5 \\ y=2z+7 \end{cases}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
s\equiv \begin{cases} x=3z+\alpha \\ y=z+\beta\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $P_u=(3u-5,2u+7,u)$ for $u\in \mathbb{R}$ is a point along the line $r$ and $Q_v=(3v+\alpha,v+\beta,v)$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}$ is a point along the line $s$. Therefore we should find real numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that
$$10=\left(\mbox{distance}(r,s)\right)^2=\min_{u,v\in\mathbb{R}}|P_u-Q_v|^2=\min_{u,v\in\mathbb{R}} f(u,v)=f(u_0,v_0)$$
where
$$f(u,v)=(3u-5-3v-\alpha)^2+(2u+7-v-\beta)^2+(u-v)^2.$$
and $(u_0,v_0)$ is the point where the minimum is attained that is  where the gradient of $f$ is zero. Now
$$(f_u,f_v)=(28u-2-24v-6\alpha-4\beta,-24u+16+22v+6\alpha+2\beta)=(0,0)$$
implies 
$$(u_0,v_0)=(-17/2-3\alpha/10+\beta,-10-3\alpha/5+\beta)\implies f(u_0,v_0)=5/2+\alpha+\alpha^2/10.$$
Can you take it from here?